# Raspberry PI gitlab-runner not able to run jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup Raspberry PI and installed gitlab-runner service. We also have our own privately managed Gitlab server. I have registered a gitlab runner and started it on my Raspberry PI. On my Repository, I have created a very simple **.gitlab-ci.yml** script:

```
stages:
  - test

test-job:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - raspberrypi
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"
    - ls -l
```

I have registered runner with the following command:

```
gitlab-runner register  --url https://xxx-test.test.lt  --token glrt-sauNM8P5zjAZY-C8HYWL
```

and ran it :

```
gitlab-runner run
```

As you can see from above, I am just trying to execute very basic shell command on my Raspberry PI gitlab runner. The job fails due to the reason:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on Raspberry PI HIL runner sauNM8P5z, system ID: s_0ae6b2582ae5
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on raspberrypi...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/gitlab-runner/builds/sauNM8P5z’: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

On my Raspbery PI, I see the following logs:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:/home/gitlab-runner $ gitlab-runner run
Runtime platform                                    arch=arm64 os=linux pid=6858 revision=102c81ba version=16.7.0
Starting multi-runner from /home/lukas/.gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0 max_builds=0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...

Configuration loaded                                builds=0 max_builds=1
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0 max_builds=1
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0 max_builds=1
Initializing executor providers                     builds=0 max_builds=1
Checking for jobs... received                       job=783 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git runner=sauNM8P5z
Added job to processing list                        builds=1 job=783 max_builds=1 project=121 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git
WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1
                 duration_s=0.256630484 job=783 project=121 runner=sauNM8P2z
Appending trace to coordinator...ok                 code=202 job=783 job-log=0-919 job-status=running runner=sauNM8P5z sent-log=0-918 status=202 Accepted update-interval=1m0s
Updating job...                                     bytesize=919 checksum=crc32:107c6b65 job=783 runner=sauNM8P5z
Submitting job to coordinator...ok                  bytesize=919 checksum=crc32:107c6b65 code=200 job=783 job-status= runner=sauNM8P5z update-interval=0s
Removed job from processing list                    builds=0 job=783 max_builds=1 project=121 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git
Checking for jobs... received                       job=784 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git runner=sauNM8P5z
Added job to processing list                        builds=1 job=784 max_builds=1 project=121 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git
WARNING: Job failed: exit status 1
                 duration_s=0.211797582 job=784 project=121 runner=sauNM8P2z
Appending trace to coordinator...ok                 code=202 job=784 job-log=0-919 job-status=running runner=sauNM8P5z sent-log=0-918 status=202 Accepted update-interval=1m0s
Updating job...                                     bytesize=919 checksum=crc32:be70e1cb job=784 runner=sauNM8P5z
Submitting job to coordinator...ok                  bytesize=919 checksum=crc32:be70e1cb code=200 job=784 job-status= runner=sauNM8P5z update-interval=0s
Removed job from processing list                    builds=0 job=784 max_builds=1 project=121 repo_url=https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines.git
```

I would appreciate if someone could clarify what could be the reason why my Raspberry PI gitlab runner is failing to run CI/CD job.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled and installed gitlab-runner from scratch and that seemed to fix the issue.